# Why is L-BFGS optimization faster when binary features have been standardized?

Tags: logistic, optimization, regularization, computational-statistics, standardization

I have a question related to standardization of binary features within a regularized logistic regression. Suppose that you have a model where all the features are binary (the result of applying the [hashing trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_hashing)) so, it's not necessary to apply it.

The problem comes when I try to train the model using LBFGS, why does the standardized system converge faster? (For example, the standardized version takes 9 minutes and 37 iterations while non-standardized takes 7 hours and 4992 iterations.) What is the intuition here? The optimization function is similar in both cases, isn't it? I don't know if it's related to LBFGS or it occurs with all the optimizers, but I don't get why standardization makes it faster.

In addition, if I apply standardization to my training database, should I apply it in prediction time? What if I can't apply this standardization in prediction time for technical reasons (or design restrictions)?

Comment: I would break out the questions in the last paragraph into a new thread. They aren't very related to the bulk of this. That said, search first, especially through our threads tagged w/ [tag:cross-validation]. I'm pretty sure that issue has been addressed before.

Comment: We'll see if this helps, otherwise, I could put a bounty on it for you.

Comment: since your model is using regularisation ( l1 / l2)? this will defintely change the behaviour of the optimisation (and solution!).  I have certainly seen this sort of change with glmnet ( which isn't using LFBGS) [can't remember which way was faster].

Comment: are you using vowpalwabbit? if so you should highlight that/ tag it?

Comment: @seanv507 I'm using L2 and Spark MLLib library.

Comment: so 1 possibilty is that its the different solution engendered by l2 and scaling. if you can add variable specific regularisation you can check this. ie rescale the regularisation by the inverse of standard deviation of each input (when doing unnormalised case).

Comment: other possibility is something to do with optimisation...at least for linear regression, the 2nd derivative matrix (hessian) of your error is the uncentred covariance Matrix (don't know correct term).  so standardising makes your error surface more 'equally curved', which makes gradient descent work better... I wonder whether it also helps lfbgs?

Comment: @seanv507 it makes total sense but I supposed that second-order methods are able to avoid this kind of issues. What are the benefits of using the Hessian (or an approximation like LBFGS) then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments from a colleague:

> It would be good to look at the mean and variance of the features.
>   Actually, the mean probably isn't all that important, but I would bet
>   dimes to dollars that some of the features have VERY small variance,
>   resulting in a ill-conditioned problem.  This presents a problem for
>   any solver, but it's especially hard for first-order methods like
>   BFGS.  Recall that the first iteration of BFGS is gradient descent;
>   the next few iterations aren't all that much better.  In a full BFGS
>   implementation, the solver would eventually build a pretty decent
>   estimate of the Hessian, but L-BFGS never quite gets there because the
>   Hessian estimate is only based on m gradients, with m typically pretty
>   small.
>
> A second-order method would certainly help, but it's probably too
>   expensive.  On the other hand, preconditioning is cheap and easy.  I
>   had more than one professor tell me that you should ALWAYS
>   precondition your problems.  Even if all you do is use the diagonal of
>   your matrix as a preconditioner, it's worth it.  Because it's cheap
>   and easy and it can really pay off.  I think this is an excellent
>   demonstration of that.

Comment: It makes sense. Since L-BFGS is only an approximation, we can't consider it a second-order method. The thing here (and I think it's another question since it's 100% related to spark implementation) is that Spark standardizes the data even if you deactivate it (and applies a correction to "de-standardise"  it once the training is finished) so it doesn't make sense the differences in execution time. Anyway, as I said, it's another question.

Comment: @decay I am confused. Are you saying that the difference in execution time are nothing to do with standardisation, because spark standardises anyway, so this question is incorrect ly formulated

Comment: @seanv507 sorry for the confusion. I think that both things are causing the issue, when you disable the standardisation they do a different standardisation (in order to make the optimization easier, not working obviously). I'm trying to get a response from the spark team.

Comment: ? a naive standardisation would convert a sparse matrix to non sparse... which in turn would cause computation times to go up?

Comment: @seanv507I'm sorry I didn't get a notification for your last comment. I don't get what you mean. If you mean that all zeros will become -mean/std, because the standardization is (x-mean)/std, AFAIK they only divide by the std, so 0 will remain as 0.